# google analytics code emptying itself

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to implement google analytics to my website. I have pasted their code, which contains such function:

```
(function() {  
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

But when I upload it to my website it looks like this:

```
(function() )();
```

I made it to work (for now) by changeing code to:

```
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js" async type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-39971460-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
</script>
```

Is it by any chance good solution? Is there any risk with it?
And the actual question - why this function is becoming empty?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you see the function as "empty"? In the source code after you upload?

Comment: Uploading a file via FTP shouldn't transform the file at all - is that what you're doing? Or are you using a CMS? Or a blogging platform? Or something else? What do you mean when you say you "upload it to your website"?

Comment: It is not FTP fault - it behaves exactly the same on my localhost, before I even upload it to the server. Also the source file doesn't change - the code is still there, just in the browser it is "empty"

Comment: Additional question - is there any tool that can debug webpage, so that I can see at which moment this code is being changed?

Comment: @Siwex suggestion :Google has released [Universal Analytics](http://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en)